# Make MIN() return multiple rows?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to return more than one row based on the idea of this query:

```
SELECT MIN(colname) AS value FROM table_name
```

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Sure, group on some other field so you get multiple mins, one for each group. But otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to return more than 1 rows for this very query (the one you included in the example)

If you want to be doubly sure, add a "LIMIT 1" at the end. (that would limit the result set to 1 row, but not required here)

**EDIT**:

To answer your question "*Is there any other query that can return say 5 rows based on each row having MIN values in one column*", yes there is. You need to use a 'group by' syntax, for example:

```
SELECT category, MIN(price) AS value FROM table_name group by category
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to select the rows with the `N` (say, 10) smallest values in some column, you could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY colname ASC LIMIT 10;
```

Apologies if I've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple rows one solution is to find all rows with values that match the previously determined minimum value:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
JOIN
   (SELECT MIN(colname) AS minvalue FROM tableA) B
ON tableA.colname = B.minvalue
```

This solution differs from `GROUP BY` in that it will not otherwise aggregate (or limit) the data in the resultset. In addition, this particular solution does not consider the case of `NULL` being the "minimum value".

Happy coding.